# Display JSONArray in JTable Java

Tags: java, json, jtable

I have a `JSONArray` that needs to be inserted into a `JTable`, but from what I've googled I reached the conclusion that it's easier to insert a `JSONArray` into a `JTable` by converting it into a `JSONObject` and then I can insert it to the `JTable` using an `ArrayList`.

I've managed to convert the `JSONArray` to a `JSONObject` as shown below, but I'm stuck when I try to convert it into an `Arraylist` and then inserting it into the `JTable`. Can you tell me how to do it? Is there an easier way to insert the `JSONArray` into a `JTable`?

**JSONArray:**

```
[{"FOODID":"Jus Alpukat","PRICE":"7000","NUM":"1","RES":"7000.0","ORDERID_FK":""},{"FOODID":"Ice Cream","PRICE":"5000","NUM":"10","RES":"50000.0","ORDERID_FK":""}]
```

**JSONObject:**

```
 {"RES":"7000.0","PRICE":"7000","NUM":"1","FOODID":"Jus Alpukat","ORDERID_FK":""}
 {"RES":"50000.0","PRICE":"5000","NUM":"10","FOODID":"Ice Cream","ORDERID_FK":""}
```

**JSONArray to JSONObject conversion program:**

```
JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(lineRead);
List<Data> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++) {

    JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
    Data data = new Data();

    data.foodid = jsonObj.getString("FOODID");
    data.price = jsonObj.getString("PRICE");
    data.num = jsonObj.getString("NUM");
    data.res = jsonObj.getString("RES");

    dataList.add(data);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JTable` can use a `Vector<Vector<String>>` as a simple table model. So if you just need to display the values the following rather simplistic approach works:

```
    JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(lineRead);
    Vector<Vector<String>> dataList = new Vector<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++) {

        JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
        Vector<String> data = new Vector<>();

        data.add(jsonObj.getString("FOODID"));
        data.add(jsonObj.getString("PRICE"));
        data.add(jsonObj.getString("NUM"));
        data.add(jsonObj.getString("RES"));

        dataList.add(data);
    }

    Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<>();
    columnNames.add("foodId");
    columnNames.add("price");
    columnNames.add("num");
    columnNames.add("res");

    JTable table = new JTable(dataList, columnNames);
```

For a more sophisticated solution you have to use a `TableModel`.

Comment: why suddenly there's tableData? is the use of columnNames only for rename the column? @alexander.egger

Comment: @azizahn sorry thats a typo. changed it